Probability a random integer has an $x$-bit prime factor (or two)
If $N$ is a random $y$-bit integer, what is the probability that it has

at least one $x$-bit prime factor?
at least two $x$-bit prime factors?

I am assuming $x$ is large and that $y > x$.
If $N$ is a $y$-bit integer then $2^{y-1} \leq N < 2^y$.  Similarly, we say a prime factor $p$ has $x$ bits iff $2^{x-1} \leq p < 2^x$.
For the first question, I have the following attempt.
For a random integer $N$ and prime $p$, the probability that $p$ divides $N$ is approximately $\frac{1}{p}$. Hence the probability that $N$ is not divisible by any $x$-bit prime is approximately:
$$\prod_{2^{x-1} \leq p < 2^x} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right).$$
Using Mertens' third theorem, we know that
$$\prod_{p \leq n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \approx \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln{n}}$$
where $\gamma$ is the  Euler-Mascheroni constant.  Therefore,
$$\prod_{2^{x-1} \leq p < 2^x} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \approx \frac{\ln(2^{x-1})}{\ln(2^x)} = \frac{x-1}{x}.$$
Therefore the probability that there is an $x$-bit prime factor is approximately $1 - \frac{x-1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}$.

Is this result correct asymptotically?

The second part of the question is:

what is the approximate probability of having at least two $x$-bit
prime factors?

Numerical experiments suggest it might be close to $\frac{1}{2x^2}$.
This is related but is not about asymptotics

By 'x bit prime factor', do you mean 2 <= p < 2^x or 2^(x-1) <= p < 2^x?

@SimonGoater I added a clarifying sentence.

Intuitively you'd expect the number of $x$-bit prime factors to have Poisson distribution.  If the expectation $\lambda$ of such a distribution is close to $0$ (so that $e^{-\lambda} \approx 1$), then $P(X \geq 1) \approx P(X=1)\approx\lambda$ and $P(X \geq 2) \approx P(X = 2) \approx \frac{1}{2} \lambda^2$.  This matches the numerical experiments you performed for question 2.
